# MySQL returning incorrect data?

Tags: sql, mysql, myisam

Recently an issue came up in the Django community regarding testing of MySQL (using MyISAM).

Here's the django ticket: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14661

One of the Django core developers came up with this test and many of us have been able to replicate it. Anyone have a guess as to what we are running into here? Is it simply a bug in MySQL or am I missing something?

Here's the test code and queries:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testapp_tag`;
CREATE TABLE `testapp_tag` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` integer
);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t1", NULL);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t2", 1);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t3", 1);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t4", 3);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t5", 3);
SELECT `testapp_tag`.`id`, `testapp_tag`.`name`, `testapp_tag`.`parent_id` FROM `testapp_tag` WHERE NOT ((`testapp_tag`.`id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `testapp_tag` U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN `testapp_tag` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`parent_id`) WHERE U1.`id` IS NULL) AND `testapp_tag`.`id` IS NOT NULL)) ORDER BY `testapp_tag`.`name` ASC;
SELECT `testapp_tag`.`id`, `testapp_tag`.`name`, `testapp_tag`.`parent_id` FROM `testapp_tag` WHERE NOT ((`testapp_tag`.`id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `testapp_tag` U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN `testapp_tag` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`parent_id`) WHERE U1.`id` IS NULL) AND `testapp_tag`.`id` IS NOT NULL)) ORDER BY `testapp_tag`.`name` ASC;
```

Here's the output:

```
mysql> SELECT `testapp_tag`.`id`, `testapp_tag`.`name`, `testapp_tag`.`parent_id` FROM `testapp_tag` WHERE NOT ((`testapp_tag` .`id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `testapp_tag` U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN `testapp_tag` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`parent_id`) WHERE U1.`id` IS  NULL) AND `testapp_tag`.`id` IS NOT NULL)) ORDER BY `testapp_tag`.`name` ASC;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | name | parent_id |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | t1   |      NULL |
|  3 | t3   |         1 |
|  5 | t5   |         3 |
+----+------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `testapp_tag`.`id`, `testapp_tag`.`name`, `testapp_tag`.`parent_id` FROM `testapp_tag` WHERE NOT ((`testapp_tag` .`id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `testapp_tag` U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN `testapp_tag` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`parent_id`) WHERE U1.`id` IS NULL) AND `testapp_tag`.`id` IS NOT NULL)) ORDER BY `testapp_tag`.`name` ASC;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | name | parent_id |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | t1   |      NULL |
|  3 | t3   |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Omitting the prompt information (mysql>) makes it easier for us to copy/paste so we can test on our systems if possible.

Comment: which part is wrong? just the last query? I see.. the same query loses 1 record on 2nd run

Answer (score 4):

This form works reliably:

```
SELECT T.`id`, T.`name`, T.`parent_id`
FROM `testapp_tag` T
WHERE NOT (T.`id` IN (
    SELECT U0.`id`
    FROM `testapp_tag` U0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `testapp_tag` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`parent_id`)
    WHERE U1.`id` IS NULL))
ORDER BY T.`name` ASC;
```

The NOT + IN + additional filter mix seems to throw MySQL out. It is definitely a bug.

The test in the NOT() looks for 2 parts. If the first part is true, the 2nd cannot possibly be true, regardless of whether the field can be null or not.  It is a redundant clause that seems to be the cause of the bug.

Taking a cue from ScrumMeister's answer, I confirm that the bug is due to some sort of caching against the last inserted ID against the AUTO_INCREMENT.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testapp_tag`;

CREATE TABLE `testapp_tag` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` integer
);

start transaction;
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t1", NULL);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t2", 1);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t3", 1);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t4", 3);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t5", 3);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t6", 3);
INSERT INTO `testapp_tag` (`name`, `parent_id`) VALUES ("t7", 3);
commit;

delete from testapp_tag where id = 6;   #######

explain extended
SELECT T.`id`, T.`name`, T.`parent_id`
FROM `testapp_tag` T
WHERE NOT (T.`id` IN (
    SELECT U0.`id`
    FROM `testapp_tag` U0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `testapp_tag` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`parent_id`)
    WHERE U1.`id` IS NULL) AND T.`id` IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY T.`name` ASC;
show warnings;
```

Produces this plan

```
select `test`.`t`.`id` AS `id`,`test`.`t`.`name` AS `name`,`test`.`t`.`parent_id` AS `parent_id`
from `test`.`testapp_tag` `T` where ((not(<in_optimizer>(`test`.`t`.`id`,
<exists>(select 1 AS `Not_used` from `test`.`testapp_tag` `U0` left join `test`.`testapp_tag` `U1` 
on((`test`.`u1`.`parent_id` = `test`.`u0`.`id`)) where (isnull(`test`.`u1`.`id`)
and (<cache>(`test`.`t`.`id`) = `test`.`u0`.`id`)))))) **or (`test`.`t`.`id` = 7)**)
order by `test`.`t`.`name`
```

If the insert stops at t6, and the delete is also of t6, the bug is masked because the clause added is or (test.t.id = 6) which we have already deleted in the line marked    #######

Answer (score 4):

Seems very interesting, and looks like a bug in the MySql query optimizer.

If you run this instead of the plain selects:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT `testapp_tag`.`id`, ....;
SHOW WARNINGS;
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT `testapp_tag`.`id`, ...;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Then, comparing the output from the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` warnings, You can see that the first time around, the optimizer adds to the select:

```
or (`test`.`testapp_tag`.`id` = 5)
```

Also, note that removing the `AND testapp_tag.id IS NOT NULL` from the `WHERE`, which does nothing since the field is marked as `NOT NULL`, seems to take away the issue.

Comment: I get the same warnings for both, and same plan (without show warnings).. Okay redid the query and now I see the clause. Strange!